# How to enable secure authentication (ssl,tls,starttls) in nullmailer 1.0.5. and upgrade nullmailer to 1.11

Tags: linux, email, ssl, mutt

I am using a linux based device where we use nullmailer to send email using smtp.

```
nullmailer version: 1.0.5

User-Agent: Mutt/1.5.19 (2009-01-05)
```

In the existing mechanism, our smtp server does not have any authentication.It is just a plain text.
Now we need a secure authentication for smtp.

By googling I found some work around for this,the suggestions are to change the values in 
`/etc/nullmailer/remotes`. I have changed as per the suggestions and tried to run `nullmailer-send` but no luck.

Here is the list of changes I have made in  `/etc/nullmailer/remotes` :

using theses http://blog.janjonas.net/2011-04-22/configure-nullmailer-smtp-authentication http://metz.gehn.net/2012/11/nullmailer-with-starttls/ references

```
1. smtp.gmail.com smtp --user=[GMAIL_USERNAME@gmail.com] --pass=[GMAIL_PASSWORD]
2. smtp.gmail.com smtp --auth-login --user=[GMAIL_USERNAME@gmail.com] --pass=[GMAIL_PASSWORD]
3. smtp.gmail.com smtp --port=25 --user=[GMAIL_USERNAME@gmail.com] --pass=[GMAIL_PASSWORD]
4. smtp.gmail.com smtp --port=587 --starttls --user=[GMAIL_USERNAME@gmail.com] --pass=[GMAIL_PASSWORD]
5. smtp.gmail.com smtp --port=465 --auth-login --user=[GMAIL_USERNAME@gmail.com] --pass=[GMAIL_PASSWORD] --ssl
```

None of them are working.

Again I found that the version of nullmailer(1.0.5) may not support any secure authentication (ssl/tls/starttls). I validated this concept by `--help`

See this reference : `http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/nullmailer/`

```
-p, --port=INT    Set the port number on the remote host to connect to
      --user=VALUE  Set the user name for authentication
      --pass=VALUE  Set the password for authentication
      --auth-login  Use AUTH LOGIN instead of AUTH PLAIN in SMTP
```

[You can see there is no options for ssl/tls/starttls]

So, I updated the version of nullmailer from `1.0.5 to 1.11` But when I execute `nullmailer-send` to send the queued messages in `/var/nullmailer/queue` but met with below error

```
Could not load the config
```

**Making the story short, here is the list of my concern :**

```
1. Can I secure the smtp channel using the existing version of nullmailer.
2. Is nullmailer 1.0.5 does not supprt any secured authentication. (ssl/tls/starttls)
3. If it does how can I set the security what should be the /etc/nullmailer/remotes value.
4. If I update the version from 1.0.5 to 1.11 what are the dependencies.
```

I went through almost all the links provided by google, but still in a big puzzle.

Help would be highly appreciate.
I may missed something important.

**Please ask anything if this issue is not clear to anyone.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nullmailer 1.0.5 does not support tls/ssl. Update your nullmailer to latest (1.11)